# Unable to load asset-classic ways already verified

Tags: image, flutter, dart, addition, assets

I already try to run pub get, hot reload and my sentence is right. this is my error :
Exception caught by image resource service
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/cover.jpg

Comment: Did you specified your assets im pubspec.yaml? See: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets

Comment: please share your pubspec.yaml too

Comment: while adding assets, best case rebuild by restarting.

Comment: flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/


you can add your pubspec.yaml file